# Servlet Initialization Listener

Tags: servlets, webserver, listener, servlet-listeners, web-container

I am trying to identify when a servlet is initilazed (not the init() method called), when container try to load an individual servlet ? Or, any mechanism which keeps track of servlet initialized / destroyed / pending to load.

I am aware of the ServletContextListner, which invoked on application start & shutdown. But, I am looking for kind of listener, which probably trigger on individual servlet load / destroy event.

So, scenario would be like :
 /Servlet1
 /Servlet2
An listener which trigger on servlet1 load and then for Servlet2.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is the listener you are looking for .You want to know each time a request comes in, so that you can log it.
**javax.servlet.ServletRequestListener** . Following are the methods **requestInitialized requestDestroyed**

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But, i am not looking to log each request. I am interested in identifying the when servlet is loaded by server